# Gate::after(): returning a not null value do not alter the result of the authorization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-authorization, laravel-gate

As per laravel official documentation,

> if the **after** callback returns a non-null result that result will be considered the result of the check.

But when I declare *after* callback and overwrite the value as false, it still returns the previous value.

What am I missing? How to override the value in *Gate::after* ?

```php
Gate::define('edit-settings', function ($user = null) {
    return true;
});
Gate::after(function ($user = null, $ability = null, $result = null, $arguments = null) {
    return false; //this have no effect
});

// ------------

Gate::allows('edit-settings'); // return true!
```

Comment: Do you really have Laravel 7? This behavior is similar to the previous version of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

because your 'edit-settings' gate always return a boolean value, so Gate::after is not called.

[this article can help.](https://freek.dev/1325-when-to-use-gateafter-in-laravel)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29891647)

Answer (score 0):

1. This behavior can be if you have the Laravel < 5.7
2. You process the request without authorization
3. `Gate::after(function ($user = null, $ability = null, $result = null, $arguments = null)` - params should not be null. I think it can cause this error

Comment: I'm looking at Laravel 7 documentation and I'm using Laravel 7 as well. if this does not work like that, why is it stated in the documentation like that?